# cake php form validation is not working for me

Tags: cakephp, validation

I have a a form which adds first_name and last_name of user in cakephp.
here is the code

code for view (`add.ctp`)

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('first_name',array('label'=>'First Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('last_name',array('label'=>'Last Name'));           
echo $this->Form->end('Add User');
?>
```

code for UserController (`UsersController.php`)

```
<?php
     public function add(){
          if($this->request->is('post')){
               $addData = $this->request->data;
               $this->User->create();       
               if($this->User->save($addData)){
                  $this->Session->setFlash('User has been added successfully');
                  $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));            
               }            
          }
     }    
?>
```

view code for User Model (`UserModel.php`)

```
<?php
  class UserModel extends AppModel{
   public $validate = array(
     'first_name' => array(
          'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
          'message' => 'first name should not be empty.'
      ),
     'last_name' => array(
         'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
         'message' => 'last name should not be empty.'
      )
   );   
}
?>
```

This is the code I am using, I have seen on cakebook as well and used various other rules, but no validation is working for my form. Can some please help me what could be the reason ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Your model filename is incorrect. It should be `User.php` not `UserModel.php`

Answer (score 1):

please change your file name to `user.php` if your using table name in mysql as users instead of `UserModel.php`

and your classname must be like below

```
<?php
  class User extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'User';

   public $validate = array(
     'first_name' => array(
          'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
          'message' => 'first name should not be empty.'
      ),
     'last_name' => array(
         'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
         'message' => 'last name should not be empty.'
      )
   );   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model name should be User (as your table name and controller name is users).
So try this in your model file(User.php)

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel{
public $validate = array(
 'first_name' => array(
      'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
      'message' => 'first name should not be empty.'
  ),
 'last_name' => array(
     'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
     'message' => 'last name should not be empty.'
  )
```

);
}